# Text is cut off when capturing div with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

```
//script

case "btn-download": {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("container-image")).then(function (canvas) {
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          a.download = "New image.png";
          a.click();
        });
        break;
      }

//html

<div id="container-image">
      <input id="tab-title" placeholder="Set Title"></textarea>
    </div>

//css

#container-image {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#tab-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#tab-title::placeholder {
  color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}
```

[In page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gokhz.png)

[Downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyO7K.png)

I'm creating a button that captures a div, but when I increase the font-size of the input, it cuts off the top of the text.

I tried changing the padding, margin, line-height, etc... in the css, but it didn't work, and the only way to fix it was to reduce the font size. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you manage to fix the problem?